# How to use TensorFlow 2 without Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since version 2 of TensorFlow Keras plays a central role in the framework. At the same time, the tf.nn layers are still available and allow them to create more specific layers.

I want to migrate a project (*tf1*) that I have found on GitHub to the newest TensorFlow version. There the author used `tf.nn-layers` (e.g. *tf.nn.conv2d*) and luckily those layers and functions still exist in the latest version. However, I can not find a tutorial that creates a model only out of these layers and which refers to Tensorflow 2.x (without sessions, etc.).

Since most of the elements in TensorFlow are handled as tensors I have tried to specify my model the following way so that I can use for example the *predict* functionality:

```py
my_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_nn_input_layer, outputs=my_nn_output_layer)
```

Unfortunately, the output of this does not work for me and also does not seem right.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate might be helpful. the keras layers use `tf.nn` methods under the hood

Comment: `tf.nn.*` layers are the operations the network does. You must provide the variables on which these operations work. The hndling of variables was one of the major changes from TF1 to TF2, so you'll need to look up and understand that to port your network.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Cheers @GPhilo